# Assert + Selenium 4 relative locators

Tags: java, selenium, assert, assertion

I wonder if I can use the new Selenium 4 relative locators in my assertions.

For example something like that:

```
Assert.assertTrue("", myWonderfulLogo.above(myWonderfulNavBar));
```

There's a crooked way to do this but I wonder if there's a more straightforward way to do it: https://github.com/angiejones/selenium-relative-locators/blob/master/src/test/java/books/RelativeLocatorsTests.java

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to write a test to see if your `myWonderfulLogo` is above `myWonderfulNavBar`, then relative locators can help you, although they will need to be converted to web elements first. All relative locators are doing is further constraining regular locations (xpaths, by id, by name, css selectors etc).

For example if I wanted to look for an element with a certain id, but I only wanted to look for elements that were above a certain other element (instead of searching the entire document) relative locators are good for that.

Say your `myWonderfulLogo` has the following html:

```
<img id="logo" ... />
```

And your `myWonderfulNavBar` has the following html:

```
<nav id="nav" ... />
```

Then to write a test to make sure your logo is above your nav bar, you could write something like this:

```
var myWonderfulLogo = driver.findElements(By.id("logo").above(By.id("nav")));
Assert.assertTrue(myWonderfulLogo.size() > 0);
```

If your logo isn't above the nav bar, `findElements` will have found no elements, so comparing if it's greater than 0 means that at least one thing was found. Hope that helps explain things.

Bonus food for thought: how will your test perform on different devices/screen sizes? With this new addition test developers will have even more to think about when testing responsive websites :)